# Does any router switch from one internet source to another if one is down?

Tags: router, switch

I have internet source coming from local provider in a remote area that is unstable. let's call it Internet 1. Internet 1 is connected to an 8 port switch. On that same switch, 3 access points (APs) routers are connected each through its own wan port. Every AP has a set of devices connected wirelessly. Each AP has different SSID name.

When Internet 1 goes off for some reason, we lose internet on all APs and devices.

I wonder if I buy a 4G router with SIM card and connect one of its LAN ports to the same switch, when Internet 1 is down, would all of the 3 APs' WANs automatically switch to read the internet connection from the 4G router?

Comment: You have to find a router that would support multiple WAN connections and manage failover. This is not a default function and connecting it to a LAN port won’t do much.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, you'll need a router capable of WAN failover.
Every linux system with enough network ports could be configured to do exactly that, but there are easier solutions.
[OPNsense](https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/how-tos/multiwan.html), PFsense and [dd-wrt](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Dual_WAN_with_failover) to name a few, are cost-effective solutions capable of failover WAN connections.

dd-wrt is built as custom firmware for consumer-grade devices, while OPNsense and PFsense are BSD-based and capable of running on x64 and ARM hardware like servers or PCs.

Comment: Decent answer. But I don’t think the message of being able to flash a router’s firmware is clear here. That is what OPNsense, PFsense and dd-wrt are useful for: Getting a decent router that can be flashed to use them.

Comment: this will do exactly what i want TP-Link Safestream Multi WAN Router | 4 10/100M WAN Ports w/Load Balance Function | Portal Authencation Access Management | Abundant Security Features | Lightning Protection(TL-R470T+)

Answer (score 0):

#### Possibly an answer:

*(I'm not fluent enough with network setups to create a good example for you from what is below, AND this is also in a "transitory" state so what is below is not yet fully configured, sorry.)*

I have

1. a Netgear GS108T (switch) for my LAN,
2. one of the ports has a Netgear M1 mobile router attached.
3. The router's DHCP hands out local IP:s for 192.168.1.0/24
4. A laptop, and a RaspberryPi are both connected to the switch
5. The below is active **on the laptop**, allowing IT to access the internet in that manner; **unlikely** to work on the Raspberry or even possible from the router's admin pages - need more similar things, at least on the pi.)

```
#
# mobile hotspot enabled on Phone - 192.168.43.0/24 link is up
# due to the metric being lower than for 192.168.1.0/24 
# it acts (works) as "preferred link"
#

$ ip route
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 90 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno2 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.98 metric 100 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.29 metric 90 

#
# mobile hotspot DISABLED seconds ago, -  192.168.43/24 link down
#

$ ip route
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 90 linkdown 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno2 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.98 metric 100 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.29 metric 90 linkdown 

#
# mobile hotspot disabled, after 10(-ish?) seconds
#

$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno2 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.98 metric 100 
hannu@gflap ~ bash (P)PID=(2062)5024, s=0

$
```

Now, would not that be very similar to what you want?

I'm not saying this is exactly fluent, you may need to refresh webpages in you browser as the switch has been done - but my experience is; that is about it.

If you have a software (SW) keeping a connection, you **might** actually have more trouble while that SW is active (e.g. towards a server).

**Ref:** `man ip-route` and *google* to set this up